# How to access variables in angularjs $http service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I have my controller and it fetches data from 2 json files using $http service.
This data is stored inside $scope variables like $scope.name and $scope.application.
But I am unable to parse over both these variables inside the same controller.

***The commented portion of the code throws me error "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined as it cannot find these two variables.***

Can some one please help me solve this?

```
    var phonecatControllers = angular.module('phonecatControllers', []);

    phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneListCtrl',['$scope', '$http','$log', function ($scope, $http,$log) 
{
    $http.get('server/user/details.json').success
    (function(data) 
      {
        $scope.users = data;
        /*$scope.users = data.splice(0, n);*/ //Restricts to 'n' users
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.users.length; i++) 
        {
            $log.info($scope.users[i].name);
        }
      }
    );



    $http.get('server/user/software/application.json').success
    (function(data) 
      {
        $scope.applications = data;
        /*$scope.users = data.splice(0, n);*/ //Restricts to 'n' users
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.applications.length; i++) 
        {
            $log.info($scope.applications[i].application);
        }
      }
    );


    /*for (var i = 0; i < $scope.users.length; i++) 
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < $scope.applications.length; j++) 
            {
                if($scope.users[i].application === $scope.applications[j].application)
                {
                    $log.info($scope.users[i].application );
                    $log.info($scope.applications[i].application);
                }
            }

        }*/
}
    ]
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend the usage of [`$q.all()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) to resolve multiple promises and keep the API call independent

> Combines multiple promises into a single promise that is resolved when all of the input promises are resolved.

```
var phonecatControllers = angular.module('phonecatControllers', []);
phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$log', '$q', function($scope, $http, $log, $q) {
    var userDetailPromise = $http.get('server/user/details.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.users = data;
        /*$scope.users = data.splice(0, n);*/ //Restricts to 'n' users
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.users.length; i++) {
            $log.info($scope.users[i].name);
        }
    });
    //Read application
    var applicationPromise = $http.get('server/user/software/application.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.applications = data;
        /*$scope.users = data.splice(0, n);*/ //Restricts to 'n' users
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.applications.length; i++) {
            $log.info($scope.applications[i].application);
        }
    });

    $q.all([
        userDetailPromise,
        applicationPromise
    ]).then(function() {
        //Perform desired when both promises are resolved
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.users.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < $scope.applications.length; j++) {
                if ($scope.users[i].application === $scope.applications[j].application) {
                    $log.info($scope.users[i].application);
                    $log.info($scope.applications[i].application);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}]);
```

---

As you are using `$http`, which async in nature you are getting the error.

For, simplest solution use the following. Here we are waiting for both the async request to complete and then proceed with desired operation.

```
var phonecatControllers = angular.module('phonecatControllers', []);
phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$log', function($scope, $http, $log) {
    $http.get('server/user/details.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.users = data;
        /*$scope.users = data.splice(0, n);*/ //Restricts to 'n' users
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.users.length; i++) {
            $log.info($scope.users[i].name);
        }


        //Read application
        $http.get('server/user/software/application.json').success(function(data) {
            $scope.applications = data;
            /*$scope.users = data.splice(0, n);*/ //Restricts to 'n' users
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.applications.length; i++) {
                $log.info($scope.applications[i].application);
            }


            //Perform desired
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.users.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < $scope.applications.length; j++) {
                    if ($scope.users[i].application === $scope.applications[j].application) {
                        $log.info($scope.users[i].application);
                        $log.info($scope.applications[i].application);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
    /**/
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Satpal.. It worked!!!
I shall accept this answer ..
If possible can you explain where the glitch was please....

Comment: @JMD, Here we are waiting for both the async request to complete and then proceed with desired operation.

Comment: As both calls are independent, I don't think its good to wait for first call to finish then only call the other one. Let them call independently and watch the response and do the manipulation later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$watch` or `$watchCollection`

```
 var phonecatControllers = angular.module('phonecatControllers', []);

   phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneListCtrl',['$scope', '$http','$log', function ($scope, $http,$log) 
    {
        $http.get('server/user/details.json').success
        (function(data) 
          {
            $scope.users = data;
            /*$scope.users = data.splice(0, n);*/ //Restricts to 'n' users
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.users.length; i++) 
            {
                $log.info($scope.users[i].name);
            }
          }
        );



        $http.get('server/user/software/application.json').success
        (function(data) 
          {
            $scope.applications = data;
            /*$scope.users = data.splice(0, n);*/ //Restricts to 'n' users
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.applications.length; i++) 
            {
                $log.info($scope.applications[i].application);
            }
          }
        );

    $scope.$watchCollection("[users, applications]", function(newVal, oldVal) { 
    if (newVal !== oldVal) {
        for (var i = 0; i < newVal[0].length; i++) 
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < newVal[1].length; j++) 
                {
                    if(newVal[0][i].application === newVal[1][j].application)
                    {
                        $log.info(newVal[0][i].application );
                        $log.info(newVal[1][i].application);
                    }
                }
    }
            }
    });

    }
        ]
        );
```